# How to log CSS and JS errors

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, vb.net

We have a huge solution composed from a lot of .ascx controls + only one ASPX page  + only one master page. The master page loads a shared Css file and shared JS file.
We are trying to clean it. We want each control loads its own css and Js, not the Master page to load the shared files.

1. Is there any way to know which css and Js is used by each
   control.
2. Is there any way, by code (C#, VB or JS), to log css
       and js errors

I want to detect JS and CSS errors like missing functions or classes and log them into a file.txt not in the console of the browser

Comment: what are css-errors to you?

Comment: Use console.log() to log css and js errors.